# In Vagrant is it possible to skip a folder when using NFS?

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

Ever since I started using Vagrant I've used the default NFS folder syncing. It works so well that I have been hesitant to change to one of the other methods, but I may need to. I really want to skip the syncing of certain folders inside my project, but from reading the documentation I can't find a way to skip folders unless I switch to Rsync from NFS.

I'm wondering if there is actually a way to skip certain folders in NFS. If there's not and I do switch to Rsync to get that capability, could there be unexpected consequences?

Thanks Vagrant experts!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately at this time it is not. You would have to switch to using `rsync` or specify the folders you want to sync in a more detailed manner.

Regarding unexpected consequences, if you switch to rsync you need to understand that using `rsync` is a "one way sync." From the [rsync documentation](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/rsync.html).

> The rsync synced folder does a one-time one-way sync from the machine running to the machine being started by Vagrant.

Any changes you make in guest machine will be over written by host when syncing. You will lose the functionality where changes in the guest in a shared folder are also reflected in the host. This is an important differentiator when using `rsync` for Vagrant.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Switching to Rsync wouldn't work for me, so I'll have to live without excluding folders right now.

Comment: What about specifying the folders you want to sync in a more detail manner?